# Potential NullPointerAccess

Tags: java

```
public void addValues(final Set<String> values) {
    if (values != null || !values.isEmpty()) { //compiler warning here on values.isEmpty(). Null pointer access: The variable values can only be null at this location            
    }
}
```

Why am I seeing this NullPointerAccess warning, though I am guarding against the null in the first check. If the value is null first check would fail and it will return without even going to the second check.

Can I ignore this warning.

I am using Eclipse for development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may think you're guarding against `null`, but you're not. If `values` is `null`, then `values!=null` will be false (so the next condition will need to be evaluated) and then `!values.isEmpty()` will raise a `NullPointerException`.

What you seem to mean is:

```
if (values!=null && !values.isEmpty()) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 4):

If `values` is `null`, `values != null` will be evaluated to false and then `!values.isEmpty()` will be evaluated, leading to a NPE.

You probably meant

`if (values != null && !values.isEmpty())`

> Can I ignore this warning.

Don't ignore warnings, they are there for something.

Answer (score 1):

> Why am I seeing this NullPointerAccess warning, though I am guarding against the null in the first check.

No you're not. If `values` is null, the first condition is false; therefore the second condition is evaluated, this is how the logical or operator works.

You probably meant to use `&&` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If `values` is `null`, the code will still try to evaluate `values.isEmpty()`. Use the `&&` operation instead:

```
if(values != null && !values.isEmpty()){
    // blah...
}
```